# R `replicate` for Julia?

Tags: r, julia

In R, I can construct a matrix of random sample by

```
> replicate(10, sample(1:100,2))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]   93   37   62   76   82   22   11   16   72    34
[2,]   95   21   13   48   59   49   38  100   90    27
```

Each column represents a pair of random sample from 1:100. I wonder if there is any Julia equivalence? I have tried the following

```
julia> [sample(1:100,2,replace=false) for i in 1:10]
10-element Array{Array{T,1},1}:
 [96,53]
 [3,31] 
 [14,23]
 [21,46]
 [78,76]
 [58,64]
 [35,85]
 [95,99]
 [88,42]
 [93,31]
```

But it is array of array, not quite what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way, but you can modify your example with `hcat` to get a matrix:

```
hcat([sample(1:100, 2) for i = 1:10]...)
```

Comment: It is not quite what I want as the two elements in a column could be the same.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know the usage of `hhat`.

Comment: In the call to `sample` here, shouldn't `replace=false` be set here?

Comment: @rickhg12hs thanks for the reminder. Didn't pay attention to the default value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a two-dimensional comprehension:

```
[sample(1:100) for i in 1:2, j in 1:10]
```

Comment: by doing this, the two elements in a column could be the same